# Cluster analysis representation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, hclust

I'm doing a cluster analysis on a large spatial dataset where x and y are the spatial coordinates. I'm using hclust and the dynamicTreeCut, and then for the representation I'm showing a scatterplot using ggplot.

But I'm unable to visualize correctly clusters, because I can show a cut only in rows or in columns.

This is a toy sample of what I want, but with my data, the cluster works only in horizontal (so I think it should cluster or visualize only for y).

```
# x and y are coordinates of points in a map

x <- sample(1:1000, 80)
y <- sample(1:1000, 80)

df <- data.frame(x,y)

hc <- hclust(dist(df, "euclidean"),"complete");

maxCoreScatter <- 0.81
minGap <- (1 - maxCoreScatter) * 3/4
groups <- cutreeDynamic(hc, minClusterSize=1, method="hybrid", distM=as.matrix(dist(df)), deepSplit=4, maxCoreScatter=maxCoreScatter, minGap=minGap)
df$group <- groups

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour=factor(groups))) + geom_point() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
p
```

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Can you add a toy example of what you are doing and what you get and what you would liket o change.

Comment: Can you color your clusters on a map?

Comment: Add a column "clusterid" to your dataframe and subsequently `melt` the dataframe. Then `geom_point(aes(color=clusterid))` should work.

Comment: Could you rephrase what you are exactly looking for? Your new example is great (+1) but to me the plot result p seems fine with clusters identified by color?